# SQL Query to get most recent date of transaction

Tags: mysql, sql

New to SQL. Can someone please tell me if my SQL query is correct? I am trying to find out how much each unique customer spent on their most recent transaction.

Table Name: Expenditure

```
Columns:

1. created_time
2. customer_id
3. spend

SELECT
distinct(customer_id), sum(spend)
FROM
Expenditure
WHERE
created_time =
(SELECT MAX(created_time))
FROM
Expenditure
GROUP BY
distinct(customer_id)
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Also DISTINCT is not a function, and it's fantastically rare to see it usefully employed in conjunction with a GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then I prefer to use window functions here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY created_time DESC) rn
    FROM Expenditure
)

SELECT customer_id, created_time, spend
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

To correct the approach you were trying to use, you can correlate the subquery to the outer query by customer:

```
SELECT customer_id, created_time, spend
FROM expenditure e1
WHERE created_time = (SELECT MAX(e2.created_time)
                      FROM Expenditure
                      WHERE e2.customer_id = e1.customer_id);
```

Comment: Thanks! In theory, is my query correct? Would it yield the same result as yours?

Comment: @giraffe Not exactly, see my updated answer.  But you can use an approach along the lines of what you were trying to do.  `ROW_NUMBER` would probably be one of the most performant ways of writing your query.